# Positioning menu within header

Tags: 7, navigation

[Just as pictured here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFlgR.jpg), I want to place the superfish menu block under the logo. Didn't manage to find any solution online. Any help?
The site works on Drupal 7, Superfish 1.8, superfish libraries 1.1 installed.

Comment: What theme are you using?  Have you tried to do this with CSS?

Comment: Use 'Featured' region to place menu block.